# How do JavaScript numbers retain their precision?

Tags: javascript

I am aware of how JavaScript numbers are all 64 bit floats, as defined in the IEEE 754 standard, and the ramifications of that when performing computations, as per:

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

(and many other questions)

What I don't understand is how JavaScript numbers somehow retain their original precision. As an example, if you assign a value of `0.1` to a variable, when viewing in the debugger, or outputting to the console it is reported as having exactly that value:

```
const foo = 0.1
console.log(foo); // reports 0.1
```

However, `0.1` is not representable as a double precision float, so that actual value of `foo` is `0.10000000149011612`. Why is it not reported as that in the above example? And where is the additional precision information stored?

Comment: The same behaviour is observed in many (most?) languages.  e.g. C: https://ideone.com/w9A2AQ